# What is the opposite side of convergence of function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Assume we define $f(x)$ on the domain of $x\ge 0$. Given the following statement,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) =0.$$
It is known that it is equivalent to
$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists X>0$, if $x\ge X$, $|f(x)| \le \epsilon$.

I want to know the negation statement for the one above, by using the $\epsilon$ language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\exists \epsilon >0 , \forall X>0, \exists x\geq X, |f(x) | >\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Prepend a negation $\neg$ and you are done.

However, to make it nicer, repeatedly use  that "$\neg\exists A\in B,$" becomes "$\forall A\in B,\neg$" and "$\neg\forall A\in B,$" becomes "$\exists A\in B,\neg$", and ultimately $\neg(A\le B)$ simplifies to $A>B$.

Comment: I don't understand why somebody voted this answer down. It clearly explains how one formally does the negation off a logical expression

Answer (score 1):

This is the logical negation:

$$\exists\,\epsilon>0,\,\forall\,X>0\,\,\exists\,x\ge X\,,\;|f(x)|>\epsilon $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\exists \varepsilon>0, \forall X>0, x \geq X \not \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq \varepsilon$$
That is, there exists some closeness of $f(x)$to 0 you can’t achieve no matter how far from $x$ is from 0 you are.